# Scale icon from sprite on retina detection

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, scss-mixins

I want to change the Icon on retina I'am using scss

this is my scss code:

```
$icon-shopping-cart-pos: -169px -289px;
$icon-shopping-cart-pos-retina: -336px -578px ;

.icon-shopping-cart {
  background: $sprite-url no-repeat $icon-shopping-cart-pos;
  width: 33px;
  height: 29px;
  @include media('retina2x') {
    background: $sprite-url-retina no-repeat $icon-shopping-cart-pos-retina;
    width: 66px;
    height: 59px;
  }
}
```

the problem is retina2x has its multiplier so the Icon is appearing twice bigger.
I need to change the Icon but keep the same height and width, and Retina will double it on its own.
This is needed so that the icon doesn't look pixelated on retina.
I tried with `background-size` but the icon disappears when adding the property.
for the media mixin I'am using [include-media](https://github.com/eduardoboucas/include-media)

My HTML:

```
<button
          type="button"
          @click="handleOnCartClick"
          class="ml-4 button-green btn-cart"
        >
          <i class="icon-shopping-cart  " />
        </button>
```

Thanks for reviewing my question and helping me.

Comment: Why is this tagged as being related to the SAS software?  Are you using this HTML with some SAS program or report?

Comment: @Tom he means `sass` the CSS preprocessor not the `SAS (software as service)` that you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various kinds of scss tricks I found the solution.
The idea is to scale the whole retina sprite not only the icon.

```
.icon-futalis-vet-green {
  background-image: $sprite-url;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: $icon-cart-pos;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  @include media('retina2x') {
    background-image: $sprite-url-retina !important; 
    background-size:324px 920px !important;
  }
}
```

My initial sprite has a width x height of 324x920  and my retina is double the size.

So by scaling the retina sprite to half size I can treat my sprite like normal size and I don't need to change the icons positions.
The icon won't look pixelated because I'm scaling it to half size
and the retina multiplier (pixel ratio) will restore it to the original size and it will look the same

Hope someone find this useful.